# Actions in InheritedResources::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scaffolding

Due to scaffolding I get

```
class CommentsController < InheritedResources::Base
```

In it not a single action shown.
But when I add

```
resources :comments
```

in routes and url

```
http://localhost:3000/comments/13
```

it work properly but I can't understand from where this action inherit. I want to custom that action. Is it possible?

Comment: How did you generated the scaffold?

Comment: Seems you installed [**inherited_resources**](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) gem.

Comment: No but active-admin gem installed

Answer (score 0):

This is due to  gem `inherited_resources` check this  http://railscasts.com/episodes/230-inherited-resources

Inside the controller define method which you want to override like for create eg:-

```
def create
  create! { products_path }
end
```